# Duplicated rows on getting Categories of a Publication

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a table of Publications

```
Id  | Title        | Content   ...
1   | 'Ex title 1' | 'example content 1'
2   | 'Ex title 2' | 'example content 2'
...
```

And a table of Categories

```
CategoryId  | PublicationId
1           | 1
2           | 1
2           | 2
3           | 2
...
```

So a Publication could have one or many categories.

I am trying to get the first 10 publications and their categories on a single query, like that:

```
SELECT [Publication].Id, [Publication].Title, [Publication].Content, [PublicationCategory].CategoryId
FROM [Publication]
LEFT JOIN [PublicationCategory] ON [Publication].Id = [PublicationCategory].Id
ORDER BY [Publication].Id DESC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

But I am getting duplicated values because of diferents categories ids, which is the better way to get 10 publications and their categories and not getting duplicated rows (because of duplicated rows, i got duplicated publications)

Comment: If you don't want duplicate in that case which [PublicationCategory].CategoryId the query should pick?

Comment: @PSK If I have duplicated values the OFFSET won't work to get 10 differents publications, I'd like to get all categories of each publication and then set it to an object on the backend, and I don't know how is the best way to do it

Answer (score 2):

You can first pick the `TOP 10` Publications and then put a `JOIN` with the Category table like following query to get all the categories.

```
SELECT [Publication].*,[PublicationCategory].[categoryid]
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 10 [Publication].id, 
           [Publication].title, 
           [Publication].content 
    FROM   Publications [Publication] 
    ORDER BY [Publication].Id DESC 
) [Publication]
INNER JOIN  Categories [PublicationCategory] 
          ON  [Publication].id = [PublicationCategory].publicationid
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/IEVZ34246)</kbd>**

Comment: The fact is I still getting, on the backend, multiple objects on the List<Publication>, and I like to get a single Publication with a List<Category>

Comment: Not sure if i get you, above query will give you 10 repeating publication for each category. To populate the entities at your application you need to create the collection accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to number your publlication, and then `JOIN` onto your table `PublicationCategory` and filter on the value of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT P.Id, P.Title, P.Content,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.ID DESC) AS RN
    FROM Publication P)
SELECT RNs.Id, Rns.Title, RNs.Content,
       PC.CategoryId
FROM RNs 
     LEFT JOIN PublicationCategory PC ON RNs.Id = PC.Id
WHERE RNs.RN <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think the best answer is the @PSK's but What if a publication is not categorized? (weird case but if is not validated maybe could happen) so you can add a left join and always get at least the 10 publications, if a  publication has no category you still will get it but with a NULL category

```
SELECT [Publication].*,[PublicationCategory].[categoryid]
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 10 [Publication].id, 
           [Publication].title, 
           [Publication].content 
    FROM   Publications [Publication] 
    ORDER BY [Publication].Id DESC 
) [Publication]
LEFT JOIN  Categories [PublicationCategory] 
          ON  [Publication].id = [PublicationCategory].publicationid
```

Comment: A Publication always has almost one Category (One to Many relation)

Comment: Saying that @PKS deserves the credit, try his option just change LEFT by INNER join